# Matching Id with that of an object in an array

Tags: c#

what is a better way of implementing this pattern?:

```
void ValidateId(int Id, MyObject[] objects)
{
    foreach (var myObject in objects)
    {
        if (Id == myObject.Id){
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid Id");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, I would not throw an exception unless the situation is exceptional.  Rather, prefer to return a bool and handle a return value of false with a nice friendly error message.

as for validating, you can use Linq....

```
bool ValidateId(int Id, MyObject[] objects)
{
   return objects.Any( o=>o.Id == Id );
}
```

Comment: Yep the case of an invalid id requires an exception in my code. I am not very familiar with Linq so perhaps it is time for me to start using it more, cheers.

Comment: @lockstock: here it will return false if the id is invalid.

Comment: @lockstock, if you are going to check out linq, you should look into using Linqpad. it lets you run linq queries without having to build an entire program, and it will even connect to SQL databases so you can run queries against SQL data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Contains()

http://www.dotnettoad.com/index.php?/archives/10-Array.Contains.html

Comment: Yes I could override .Equals() for myObject to only check if the Ids are equal, but is there another way?

Comment: You have left out a lot of details on how to make that method useful, particularly in light of other more straightforward ways.